# SwiftUI set default value in Data model

Tags: ios, firebase, swiftui, default-value

I am using Firebase Auth email sign up which only takes two values: Email and password. Before someone can access the comments section I want them to be forced to save a display name. So I have a User model like this:

```
struct UserModel: Identifiable, Hashable, Codable {
    var id: String
    var displayname: String = "Enter displayname"
    var email: String
```

and when they go to access the comments I am trying to use this logic to determine if they are using the default value "Enter displayname"

```
struct MotherView: View {
@EnvironmentObject var session: SessionStore
@EnvironmentObject var viewRouter: ViewRouter
@EnvironmentObject var fetchUser: FetchUser
@State private var currentPage = 0
//var userModel = UserModel(id: "", displayname: "Enter displayname", email: "")-This does not work, as the other user data is not appended to this variable, which I need elsewhere. 

func getUser() {
    session.listen()
}

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        if viewRouter.currentPages == "A" {
            Group {
            if (session.session != nil) {
                PagerView(pageCount: 3, currentIndex: $currentPage) {
                    TheRedWorkout()
                    TheHomeWorkout()
                    TheHWSWorkout()
                } } else {
                    AuthView()
                }
            }.onAppear(perform: getUser)
        } else if viewRouter.currentPages == "B" {
            TheRedWorkoutDetail()
            } else if viewRouter.currentPages == "C" {
            TheHomeWorkoutDetail()
            } else if viewRouter.currentPages == "D" {
            TheHWSWorkoutDetail()
            } else if viewRouter.currentPages == "E" {
            SettingsView()
            } else if viewRouter.currentPages == "F" {
            UpdateUserInfo()
            } else if viewRouter.currentPages == "G" {
            Group {
                if ((fetchUser.user.reduce("") { $0 + $1.displayname }) == "Enter displayname" )  {
                    ChooseDisplayname()
                } else {
                    CommentsView()
            }
        }

  }
 }.onAppear {
     FetchUser.retreiveUser() { (result) in
         switch result {
         case .success(let user):
             self.fetchUser.user.append(user)
             print("succesfully fetched user")
         case .failure(let err):
             print(err.localizedDescription)
         }
     }
 }
}
}
```

My dumby user has no displayname yet if I set it to == "Enter displayname" it passes me straight through to CommentsView().

Any help on why my default data value is not being set by my fetchUser call? Or suggestions on a better way to create this functionality?

here is where I create FetchUser:

```
class FetchUser: ObservableObject {
    @Published var user: [UserModel] = []

    static func retreiveUser( completion: @escaping (Result<UserModel, Error>) -> ()) {
        let reference = Firestore.firestore().collection("profiles").document("******vDtZ52qwZU8oqnIrSz1M2")
        getDocument(for: reference) { (result) in
            switch result {
            case .success(let data):
                guard let user = UserModel(documentData: data) else {
                    completion(.failure(AuthError.noProfile))
                    return
                }
                completion(.success(user))
                print("Document data: \(data)")
            case .failure(let err):
                completion(.failure(err))
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Would you show what is `fetchUser` and how it create `.user`?

Comment: Updated @Asperi

Answer (score 0):

Just take the instance of `UserModel` to a variable and call that variable's `.displayname` in the `if else` statement as follows:

```
Group {
    if (userModel.displayname == "Enter displayname") {
        ChooseDisplayname()
    } else {
        CommentsView()
    }
```

Here `userModel` is the instance of `UserModel` that you creating somehow may be with this `(fetchUser.user.reduce("") { $0 + $1.displayname })` line of code.

Comment: If I do this, it asks me for the parameters of UserModel, if I add my displayname as a default value in this instance, the logic works. But if I try to check the logic against my call using the email parameter, it does not work because I'm appending my retrieved user info to user, not userModel. 

I have added the entire MotherView to the edited post